# How can I search a word in whole project/folder recursively?

Tags: search, vim, find

Suppose I'm searching a class `JFactory` inside a folder and it's sub-directories.

How can I file that file which contains `class JFactory`?

I don't want to replace that word but I need to find that file that contains `class JFactory`.

Comment: It's much more convenient to not having to leave your editor/IDE.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
:vimgrep /JFactory/ **/*.java
```

You can replace the pattern `/JFactory/` with `/\<JFactory\>/` if you want full word match. `:vim` is shorthand for `:vimgrep`.

If `JFactory` or `\<JFactory\>` is your current search pattern (for example you have hit `*` on one occurrence) you can use an empty search pattern: `:vimgrep // **/*.java`, it will use last search pattern instead. Handy!

Warning: `:vimgrep`  will trigger autocmds if enabled. This can slow down the search. If you don't want that you can do:

```
:noautocmd vimgrep /\<JFactory\>/ **/*.java
```

which will be quicker. But: it won't trigger syntax highlighting or open `gz` files ungzipped, etc.

Note that if you want an external program to grep your pattern you can do something like the following:

```
:set grepprg=ack
:grep --java JFactory
```

`Ack` is a Perl-written alternative to grep. Note that then, you will have to switch to Perl regexes.

Once the command of your choice returned, you can browse the search results with those commands described in the Vim documentation at `:help quickfix`. Lookup `:cfirst`, `:cnext`, `:cprevious`, `:cnfile`, etc.

2014 update: there are now new ways to do that with `the_silver_searcher` or `the_platinum_searcher` and either `ag.vim` or `unite.vim` plugins.

Comment: For the reference: `:vim` is a short name of the `:vimgrep` command.

Comment: also note that `:lvimgrep` does the same with the location window instead of the quickfix window. Handy if you're also dealing with compiler output and don't want to go back and forth with `:colder`, `:cnewer` all the time

Comment: but still can't get the list of filename that contains the word "JFactory".

Comment: @guru: Use `:copen`, `:cnext`, `:cprev` and related commands to jump through search results. Reference is on `:help quickfix`

Comment: how to jump to the next match, `n` or `N` are useless

Comment: after :vimgrep, use `:cw` to list all of results

Comment: pls put the update at the top of the comment @benoit

Answer (score 21):

From the project root folder, run following:

```
grep -H -r 'what_you_search' * | less
```

You will get a list of folders and matching lines with that string.

Comment: can you explain what each of the operators do?

Comment: Explaining the flags and command, from `man grep`:
`-H`: Always print filename headers with output lines. And the `-r`: Recursively search subdirectories listed.

the `| less` part will "pipe" the output into the `less` program, allowing you to scroll through content using the arrows, and quit by pressing `q`.

Answer (score 10):

The Silver Searcher(https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)
highly recommended, really fast!

**install**

```
sudo pacman -S the_silver_searcher  // arch linux 
sudo apt install silversearcher-ag  // ubuntu
```

**usage**

```
$ ag keywords
```

**integrate with vim**

rking/ag.vim (https://github.com/rking/ag.vim)

after installing

```
:Ag keywords
```

Comment: Apparently that repo is deprecated as of 2016

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ctags](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_29.html) and [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) which let you jump to class and function definitions, and find where those functions/classes are used.

Answer (score 1):

This script may help:  [Filesearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3646).

Answer (score 0):

Open the command line window by:

Esc - to enssure you are in Normal mode

type q , type :

the command line should open ( it like a tmp file to write the command you can navigate as you would navigate normally in any vim file ...

type i to enter insert mode

this example will search for the to_srch string recursively bellow the current dir for all file types of type '*.js' and '*.java' but omit all file paths containing the string node_modules

```
:g/console.log/ | :vimgrep /console.log/ `find . -type f -name '*.js' -o -name '*.java' -not -path '*node_modules/*'`
```

Now wheen you :copen you could navigate with the arrow keys through the sarch results ...

you could also set those in .vimrc

```
    " how-to search recursively under the current dir for the files of type js and java but omit the
    " node_modules file paths
    ":g/console.log/ | :vimgrep /console.log/ `find . -type f -name '*.js' -o -name '*.java' -not -path '*node_modules/*'`
    " reminder open the quick fix window by :copen 20
    " reminder close the quick fix window by :ccl
```

you could omit the first :q/to_srch/ I use it to highlight the search results automatically since I have "set hlsearch" in my ~/.vimrc

Any hint how-to enable automatically the srch results from the vimgrep or in vimrc will be highly appreciated ...