# How to go all reference of a text in whole project using vim

Tags: c, linux, vim

I know this is very simple question and really there are very huge source of information but I really not able to find the solution to my question.

I have tried with `cscope` and got the references but then once I am in the file not find the way to go go to the next occurrence.

I know the use of Ctrl+] with ctags but that is not what I want.I want to go all the reference of a text one by one .

like when we want to change a prototype of a function and want to go one by one.

Hope there is some way for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search a word in whole project/folder recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950558/how-can-i-search-a-word-in-whole-project-folder-recursively)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `:tnext` and `:tprevious`.

Read the following help topics:

```
:help tags
:help ctags
:help cscope
```

---

But here is a generic "search/replace in project" method…

1. search for that string in your whole project and list the matching lines in the quickfix window:

   ```
   :vim foo **/*.py | cw
   ```
2. record your change in a simple macro:

   ```
   qq
   ciwbar<Esc>
   :cnext<CR>
   q
   ```
3. repeat that change for every match in the list:

   ```
   @q
   @@
   @@
   …
   ```

   skipping irrelevant matches with `:cnext`.

and another one…

1. open a new tab:

   ```
   :tabnew<CR>
   ```
2. populate the local argument list with files that contain your search pattern:

   ```
   :arglocal `grep -Rl foo *.js`<CR>
   ```
3. perform a global search/replace on every file in the local argument list

   ```
   :argdo %s/foo/bar/gc<CR>
   yyyynnnyyy…
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `cscope` plugin for `vim`?

After searching for something you can use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to go through the results.  If that's too cumbersome, you can add a shortcut to your `.vimrc`; for example:

`noremap nn :cnext <CR>`, which will make `nn` a shortcut for `:cnext`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for search pattern in whole project.
You can try

[ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) there is 36 contributor so it's a well done plugin using [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).
I tried it in a big project few weeks ago and it improve well my workflow.